# I need to merge my pull request into release branch but accidentally i have merged it into master branch

Tags: git, github

Actually i need to merge my pull request into `release/1.1` branch but accidentally i merged into the `master` branch. Any possibility to merge it back to release branch and remove the changes from master branch? Do we need to revert the changes or do we have any other way to move this changes into release branch?

Comment: There's a Revert button. Click it! Then make PR to merge that branch correctly

Comment: @matt, i am aware about the Revert button. Can you please check my question. I want to know if there is any other workaround other than reverting the changes?

Comment: No. How could there be? If you have superpowers you can hard reset master. But I don't advise it.   The best workaround is, next time think harder, sooner.

Answer (score 0):

> Any possibility to ... remove the changes from master branch?

Yes. You can revert or hard reset. Revert is better.

> Do we need to revert the changes

Yes. This can come in the form of a new PR whose effect is to revert the merge effect, putting the state of master back to where it was before the merge. But there is no better way to "undo" this kind of history. Hard reset on a shared branch is inadvisable.